# Is there a way to have pip upgraded for a new venv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyenv, python-venv

I am using **pyenv** installed through **homebrew**

When **pyenv local** is 3.7.1, Pip version is 18.1

```
$ pip --version
pip 18.1 from ~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

But, after creating venv and activating it

```
python -m venv myenv
source myenv/bin/activate
```

Pip version is 10.0.1

```
$ pip --version
pip 10.0.1 from ./myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

**Is there a way to have pip upgraded for a new venv?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%5Bvirtualenv%5D+installed+old+version

Answer (score 1):

Try `pip install --upgrade pip` from within the virtual environment. If on windows, try `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: that works, but i would like to have pip upgraded right after the venv creation

Comment: Do you have different versions of python installed?

Comment: yes. MacOS and Linux come with 2.7 and 3.6

Comment: @fcedillo i take it you meant python 3.7? did you install this version with homebrew or using the installation file from the python website?

Comment: i installed 3.7 through pyenv